# HTML tags inside code block

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Some times I'm showing to some OP how to change his/her code to make it work. I would like to write code blocks and then be able apply `<del>` to some statements.

For instance:

> int main() { <del>return -1;</del> return 0;}

I'm aware of the fact that the code including the text `<del>` might be present, for instance some simple XML fragment:

```
<file>
    <actions>

         <del>
         </del>  

        ...

    </actions>
</file>
```

That's why this is hard to implement or even design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that, then you should use `pre` tags instead of the indentation.

```
<pre>
<strike>This is the wrong code.</strike>
This is the correct code.
You can also use <strong>bold</strong>, <em>italic</em> and some other HTML now.
</pre>
```

Will return:

```
This is the wrong code.
This is the correct code.
You can also use bold, italic and some other HTML now.
```

Note that Markdown won't work inside `pre`-tags.

Comment: That's an option, yes. But then I'll suffer the lack of code highlight. Anyway your option is a good alternative to use when code highlight don't really matters. Thanks.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda You can still get code highlighting if you use `<code>` tags *inside* `<pre>`. I don't think it's a great idea, but it works.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Might be a bad idea for many. But right now is the only way to achive what I want. Thanks!!